# How can I cut holes using a Voronoi texture?

Tags: modeling, texturing, node-editor

Is it possible to create this picture with the voronoi texture node?
[image]

Comment: it is probably much more some play around the wireframe modifier

Comment: it's possible to explain this

Comment: No, exactly this cannot be obtained just from 3d voronoi, a smoothed 3d voronoi looks like this: http://www.3dizingof.com/3D-Printing/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/3D-Voronoi-Unicron-by-Dizingof-.7597.jpg. What you want is a wireframe and subsurf modifiers with some creasing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That can be a way to do it :

- Wireframe modifier
- Subsurface modifier

Starting from a subdivided plane :

[image]

For information, this can be extruded : <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, edge selection mode. But some bad shading, as you can see :

[image]

Another edit :

You can do nearly the same job using a skin modifier. To do it, just compose a 3D grid and set the modifiers as shown below :

[image]

Comment: How does this work on a cube?

Comment: @cegaton, did not tried... I'll do it when possible and tell here

Comment: @cegaton, edit done

Answer (score 11):

## Volume shader

It is not fast to render, it is not the most practical method, but  I cloud not resist to post this image:

[image: Voronoi Volume]

Comment: Good, but is not symmetric

Comment: Setting the randomness of the Voronoi nodes to have 0.0 randomness should result in a grid, which is symetrical

Answer (score 4):

**Cell Fracture Voronoi**

[image]

Margins have control and achieve constant width goal.

- Cell Fracture results in one plane then extruded
- Boolean difference with a Cube, yellow
- Triangulate, blue
- Detail in large

[image]

[image]

Result of Cell Fracture after steps below.  Click image to see larger version.

[image]

Simple Cube in Layer 01 with the Cell Fracture Add On showing settings. Above image.

[image]

Particle System Modifier used on Cube.

- Cube scaled rather flat
- Particle System attached to Cube.  Settings above.
- Cell Fracture add on used with settings above.  Note Margin settings. Adjust to suit your needs. Add on installed in user preferences.  See Cell Fracture tutorials if needed.
- Switch to next Layer 02 to see Cell Fracture Results CFR.  CFR multiple objects joined Control-J.
- Edit Mode. Vertex Mode. Select Vertices on Bottom Side. Delete Vertices.  Face Mode. Select Top Face. Select Similar by Normals. Vertex Mode. Selection Inverse. Delete Vertices.
- Only top flat faces remain.
- Render Image.  Use image in Compositor or as Texture.