# Inset faces individually with thickness falloff

Tags: modeling, faces, procedural

I want create from this Voronoi cells
[image: Voronoi pattern]

Structure like this(i made it by hand by Inseting Individually rows of faces with different thickness each time):

[[image: Voronoi with inset]]

I cant make it with scale tool with pivot set to "Individual origins" and proprotional falloff. This gives this result

[[image: Voronoi with inset]]

So, appreciate any advise. Thanks!

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60808/how-can-i-cut-holes-using-a-voronoi-texture)

Comment: Please add to your question or comment a copy of the text from the info window from the inset operation ... such as ... bpy.ops.mesh.inset(thickness=0.108428)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Direct Application of Inset via Script**

---

[image]

Original Vertices. Inset applied. Positive Space. Negative space in large.

[image]

Have your mesh in edit mode before running Python Script.

---

- Use at your own risk
- Inspect and Improve
- The inset has depth, thus positive and negative face selection is available by geometric surface normal in Blender.

Comment: Thank you, Atomicbezierslinger! Apresiate for your help. Your method is fine, but it makes overlapping geometry. Little bit better solution is to make inset with tiny thickness and then scale each interior face with bmesh.ops.scale. I tried to do this, but i dont know how to compose "space=Matrix()" for each face.  Can you help me with that?

Comment: When the Blender User performs an inset by hand the User can see an example of acceptable numbers in the Blender UI.  Archive your mesh by mesh duplication, scene duplication or other.  The numbers .08 and .08 are successful for my example.  You must determine the numbers are succesful for your example.    Reduce them by half repeatedly to you get an acceptable result.  Then fine tune the numbers to suit your case.  This is part of inspect and improve.  For example in the info window I just copied the manual inset .... as ... bpy.ops.mesh.inset(thickness=0.108428)

Comment: Please state how many months or years of experience you have with Python.  Example 1 month, 2 months, 1 year.  This way we can write in an efficient manner.  Do you feel comfortable reducing the numbers?  Please state which numbers you used by copying the line of Python code and pasting as a comment . Example. Here are the numbers that work for me.        t = .04 + (.04 * (d/zdepth))

Comment: A have experience with Python about 2 year, but it ocasionally experience. Here what i have without Python just regular inset with big thickness value(right) and inset with tiny thickness value and scaling faces individually. https://www.dropbox.com/s/kpbo9cd1qojgkrh/2017-08-13_20-32-23.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by converting to a curve, extruding and scaling with proportional editing, then converting back to mesh.

1) Convert to curve
[image]

2) In edit mode, select everything and set the tilt to 90°
[image]

3) Extrude the curve
[image]

4) With linear proportional editing, select a row of vertices and scale the *Radius* property (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)
[image]

5) Convert back to a mesh
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would try it this way:

1. I use a subdivided plane (Plane.000) and all its vertices are vertex group "Vertices".
2. "Target" is the upper thingy, which is one edge subdivided several times...
3. VertexWeightProximity modifier to influence the weighting of vertex group using that "Target".
4. Wireframe modifier using vertex group.
5. And finally a Shrinkwrap modifier to project everything to a Plane.002

Gives you some unwanted vertices, but, well, perhaps a good starting point...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are following the right process.Just what you need to do is select all the faces then press I(inset).After applying inset do Ctrl+I.It will select the faces you want to delete.